# Using NSString variable from Class1 as UILabel on Class 2

Tags: class, nsstring, instance

I'm having a problem is a very basic situation.
I've been reading quite a lot about it since today's morning but couldn't put it to work.

I'm grabbing a name from a UIPicker and want to exhibit this name in another view, basically, use one variable from one class in another class.

Here's the main declaration on 
ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerAlunos;
    NSMutableArray *arrayAlunos;
    NSString *alunoAtual;
}

- (IBAction)botaoSelecionado:(UIButton *)sender;
- (void)definaAluno:(NSString*)oNome;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerAlunos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayAlunos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *alunoAtual;

@end
```

and on ViewController.m I have it defined with the definaAluno:

```
- (void)definaAluno:(NSString*)oNome {
    oNome = self.alunoAtual;
}

- (IBAction)botaoSelecionado:(UIButton *)sender; {
    NSInteger linha = [pickerAlunos selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selecionado = [arrayAlunos objectAtIndex:linha];
    self.alunoAtual = selecionado;
}
```

So, on another class ELTDDimensions.m I use lazy declaration to initialize it but it returns null.

```
- (ViewController *)student {
    if(!student) {
        student = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return student;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.studentLabel.text = self.student.alunoAtual;        
}
```

and this last line is getting a null value.
studentLabel and student are properly declared on ELTDimension.h as

```
    ViewController *student;
    IBOutlet UILabel *studentLabel;
```

Can someone help me please?